# NGINX + PHP5-FPM Redirects not working (index.php/install/)

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I've been wracking my brain on this one - so I've got NGINX up and running, it serves `phpinfo()` no issue, but I'm attempting to install a monitoring script that attempts to call the url:

> http://example.com/index.php/install/

However I end up with a 404 not found, as nginx appears to not be trying to run this as `index.php/install/` which appears to be the intended action of the script coder.

My nginx conf segment in question(I'm almost positive this is the issue):

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php  =404;
                    autoindex on;
    }
```

Could anyone assist in troubleshooting this very, very frustrating issue? Prior to this, it was kicking **500 SERVER ERROR's**, now I've got it down to **404 not found** when attempting to load this install script. I'm more well versed with Apache `.htaccess` files and probably should have gone that route considering the author must have intended it -- regardless, cheers in advance!

Comment: I expect your PHP `location` block has a terminating `$`. You are probably executing bare php scripts but not those with path info attached. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).